# For .NET 3.5 how would you make a thread-safe get or add cache?

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have starting working with some .NET 3.5 code and found the following extension method being used for a cache::

```
public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> @this, TKey key,Func<TKey,TValue> factory,bool useLocking)
{

    TValue value;
    if(!@this.TryGetValue(key,out value))
    {
        if (useLocking)
        {
            lock ((@this as ICollection).SyncRoot)
            {
                if (!@this.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                {
                    @this[key] = value = factory(key);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            @this[key] = value = factory(key);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

The cache in question is keyed by string keys, and with useLocking = true. It is always being accessed by this method (there is no stray `TryGetValue`). There is also no issue in using the `SyncRoot` property because the dictionary is private and no where else is it being used. The double locking is dangerous because a dictionary does not support reading while it's being written to. While technically there has been no issue reported yet as the product hasn't shipped, I feel that this approach is going to lead to race conditions.

1. Switch the `Dictionary<,>` to a `Hashtable`. We'll lose type-safety but we'll be able to support the concurrency model we're after, (1 writer, multiple readers).
2. Remove the outer TryGetValue. That way every read, requires acquiring a lock. This is potentially bad for performance, but acquiring an uncontested lock should be fairly cheap.

Both are pretty crappy. 
Does anyone have a better suggestion? If this was .NET 4 code I'd just switch it to a `ConcurrentDictionary`, but I don't have that option.

Comment: Yargh! Completely un-related...but don't write code using @this. You're in a static method; don't try to make it look like an instance method.

Comment: this isn't my code! If it was my code I'd add argument validation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your suspicions are correct; there is a race condition and all methods, even `TryGetValue` need to be inside the lock in the implementation you presented.

As far as performance, you can look forward to the day that you can upgrade to .NET4 which includes a screaming-fast `ConcurrentDictionary` out of the box.  Until then, you can review James Michael Hare's analysis done here:

- C#: [The Curious ConcurrentDictionary](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/06/09/c-4-the-curious-concurrentdictionary.aspx)

Those results suggest to me that the best implementation for .NET3.5 is `Dictionary` plus `ReadWriteLockSlim` and for good measure, here's a complete implementation:

- [Thread Safe Dictionary in .NET with ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/b2afc386-13cc-4297-a327-dbf52dd7498a.aspx)

**Update:**

I read the tables wrong and it looks like `Dictionary` + `lock` is little faster than the only other serious contender `Dictionary` + `ReadWriteLockSlim`.

Comment: Funny, those results suggest to *me* that a `Dictionary` with mutex locking is the best implementation. It is faster across-the-board than the rw-lock implementation.

Comment: Oops, I scanned too fast and read that table as operations per unit time, instead of time per unit operations.

Comment: The article with the complete Thread Safe Dictionary implementation is gone, but after quite a bit of digging I think I've found the [implementation itself](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/b2afc386-13cc-4297-a327-dbf52dd7498a.aspx) (code only, no commentary/explanation).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to download [Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896), which includes backports of the collections in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace (this includes `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`) for .NET 3.5.

Comment: Those are no longer there as of 19 Oct 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the TryGetValue. I bet you won't see the concurrency problem; CLR monitors are pretty quick, and are "unfair" so that you don't see convoy or priority inversion problems.

If you do see a concurrency problem, then the next best thing is a ReaderWriterLockSlim. Unfortunately, you're going to want to make a new class for that instead of using an extension method, because you're going to need a place to store the lock.

If you go that route, be sure to stay away from upgrading from reader to writer locks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to lock the complete statement (as you stated).

However, there's a neat solution on the web to be prepared for a future .NET 4 upgrade: Have a custom class instead of a dictionary, keep the dictionary as private member variable and wrap all access to the dictionary in a thread-safe lock statement.
Detailed description can be found here: http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/02/25/thread-safe-dictionarytkeytvalue/